# Изменить структуру JSON средствами PHP

Tags: php, json

Необходимо средствами PHP привести к виду:

```js
[
  {
    "first_name":"Николай",
    "phone":"+7XXXXXXXXXX",
    "second_name":"Петров",
    "weight":"81"
  }
]
```

---

```js
[
    {
    "name":"first_name",
    "value":"Николай"
    },
    {
    "name":"phone",
    "value":"+7XXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
    "name":"second_name",
    "value":"Петров"
    },
    {
    "name":"weight",
    "value":"81"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно воспользоваться array_column, используя одну колонку как значения, а вторую как индекс

```
$arr = json_decode($json, True);
$arr = array_column($arr, 'value', 'name');
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```